# Download image from url using html/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show a images from a JSON file, which change dynamically. However it seems like this url has denied permission for hotlinking and showing image through iframes. I've come to this conclusion from following errors:

```
Refused to display 'http://www.gosugamers.net/uploads/images/teams/10649-1422301535.jpeg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

http://www.gosugamers.net/uploads/images/teams/10649-1422301535.jpeg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

My question is then how can i using html/jquery download the image without using to much memories since it will download the image everytime a user visit this page?

This is what i've tried so far

```
image1.html('<iframe  src="http://www.gosugamers.net/' + m['team 1']['image'] + '" name="imgbox" id="imgbox"></iframe>')
image1.html('<img class="team1" src="http://www.gosugamers.net/' + m['team 1']['image'] + '">')
```

Comment: I don't know about you... but it works. http://jsfiddle.net/mstc1tk2/

Comment: I really dont understand it! i've cleared my cache in browser and it still does not show the image...